# How to remove the border around the toolbar?

Tags: android, border, toolbar, android-toolbar

In my app I am using a toolbar and it seems there are borders around it that I'd like to get rid of :
[image]

and I created it like that :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and I use it like that :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I never found an attribute or styling specifying what is this border.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried it by without AppBarLayout, and it's working. Don't use AppBarLayout, just use Toolbar as it is.

Comment: Yes, works for me as well. Do you know what in the AppBarLayout makes this "shadow" ?

Comment: @Axl Sorry, Idk. But this same layout you can see in playstore app's search bar, you can try to make it beautiful like that also.

Comment: yes it works but only for post-lollipop devices. should include appbarlayout for pre-lollipop devices.

Answer (score 1):

If @joyl answer works but still you do not wish to remove your `AppBarLayout` then set `elevation` to 0 in AppBarLayout like follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```